# ID tag is not working in Firefox correctly

Tags: css, firefox

I have next code

```css
#bigmenu {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none
}

#topzindex {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #02517F;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #466A7F;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  margin-left: -40px;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  background: #49BBFF;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #466A7F;
}
```

```html
<nav id="topzindex">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="bigmenu">&#926</a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">link 1</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">link 2</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">link 3</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I want the main menu to be larger than the other items. I therefore added the id tag "bigmenu". In Chrome and Edge bigmenu works correctly. In Firexo no.

Do you known what's wrong?

PS:
Firefox version - 95.0.2 (64bit)

Comment: Please include a snippet showing why it isn't working

Comment: Chrome and Edge both work on Chromium, so they will be the same. Firefox might have a different thing when it comes to specificity in selectors, so you will have to actively do something for it, so it works on firefox as well.
Also you should not use float for layouting, use flexbox or css grid.

Comment: What does "*doesn't work correctly* in Firefox", mean exactly ? It seems to work fine in Firefox here. The only problem i see is that you have `margin-top: 10px;` on the `nav ul ul` which separates the menu from the parent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll be looking for a mistake for a while. Of course, I have another code before and after the example. When I remove it, nothing changes in Firefox. But after a 5 minutes, the menu is OK. Does it look like any cache interval?

Comment: Could be; emptying your cache and restarting your browser should take care of that if that's the case. But it could also be that it doesn't look like you want; that's why i asked what you ment with "doesnt work". like, does it just look weird? or did it simply not grow enough, or does it not function when you :hover, or ....

Comment: Yes. What i want is to resize the first element only. In firefox all elements have same text sizes. In chrome first elemet have a different text size (bigger).

Comment: If by first item you mean the parent (with `id="bigmenu"`), then it is bigger for me (on firefox). It may seem different to you because you didn't put any proper content in there. `&#926` is missing its `;`. But if i put some proper text in there (like "Like 0") it is clearly much bigger than the others.

Comment: Yes. For me too.
But it happened when I removed all the other unnecessary tags.
When I gradually return them, everything is ok. And in 10 minutes (without my intervention in the code) it will break again (cache?).
So it looks like I only need to add one tag, wait 10 minutes to see if it breaks. And do it until I find a problem.

Comment: :P yea that sounds like a poisoned cache then. Clearing it and then restarting the browser should generally fix that though.